# Is there a possibility to manipulate the url in aps.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I want manipulate the url's in my asp.net project, like for example I don't want show the names of my folders in project. To be more specific:

http:localhost:12395/Views/folder1/page.aspx - this is real url since project folder to page.

http:localhost:12395/folder1/page.aspx - this is what I want... hide the View path.

There is some trick which I can Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834065/asp-net-mvc-hide-content-directory-in-url

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you that use System.Web.Routing

a tutorial link is in:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/url-routing

and more in google ;)